# Extract MM and YYYY from timestamp datacolumn C# ConsoleApplication

Tags: c#

I have ODBC DSN connection that I bring into DataTable. Column Three is "TIMESTAMP".

I have...

BRANCH----| TYPE-----| TIMESTAMP

1---------------|   R-----------|   14/03/2013 9:42

1---------------|   R-----------|   9/01/2015 9:42

3---------------|   W-----------|   13/09/2014 9:42

2---------------|   R-----------|   1/03/2012 9:42

What I want is:

1---------------|   R-----------|   03/2013

1---------------|   R-----------|   01/2015

3---------------|   W-----------|   09/2014

2---------------|   R-----------|   03/2012

There seems to be some good example of this, but i cant find examples that will work on a Datacolumn.

So I use expression quite a bit in my code to truncate etc. That doesnt seem to work in this instance. I mean i have used like this previously

```
dcUnits.Expression = string.Format("SUBSTRING({0}, 1, 1)+''+{1}+''+{2}", "BRANCH", "TYPE", "ID");
```

i am not concerned if it is in the same column or a new column added.

thanks for your input :)

Comment: You are probably looking for [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What is your Database, SQL Server? . And what is the datatype for column TIMESTAMP?

Comment: the timestamp column is from odbc query.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you are having problem with the display of Timestamp column, so if you want to display it in the format `MM/yyyy` try this:

```
//Disregard culture info if you are from US
DateTime timeStampedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStamp, "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
string mmYYYY = timeStampedDateTime.ToString("MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: How do i use this for a full column?  the datacolumn is populated when the odbc query is brought into the datatable.